# Building binary dependencies with a package

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have the following workspace layout:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── cli
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── helper
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
└── worker
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── main.rs
```

Root `Cargo.toml` is

```
[workspace]
members = ["cli", "worker", "helper"]
default-members = ["cli", "worker"]
resolver = "2"
```

Normal `cargo build` builds `cli` and `worker` targets and places artifacts in the target directory, as expected.

The `helper` target is supposed to be built manually by developers and devops fellows by `cargo build -p helper`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to build the `worker` target as well when the `helper` target is requested explicitly. Is it possible?

Comment: Making a build script could work: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html